# Making a new column in R populated from another column, and conditional on two other columns

Tags: r

I need to make a new column (col.4) that is populated with values from an existing column (col.2) chosen as a condition of the original neighboring column (col.1) and the same values in a new (longer) neighbor column (col.3). How can this be achieved? The data would look something like this:

`col.1 col.2 col.3 col.4
     1     A     1     A
     2     B     2     B
     3     C     2     B
     4     D     3     C
     -     -     1     A
     -     -     4     D
     -     -     3     C
     -     -     4     D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make use of the 'col.3' as index (assuming it as a numeric column)

```
df1$col.4 <- with(df1, col.2[col.3])
df1$col.4
#[1] "A" "B" "B" "C" "A" "D" "C" "D"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col.1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "-", "-", "-", "-"
), col.2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "-", "-", "-", "-"), col.3 = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L), col.4 = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A", 
"D", "C", "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Thank you. But in reality, I have 432 rows in col.1/2, and 864 rows in col.3/4. So manual indexing like you have produced here won't work for my application.

Comment: @JKO. I am not doing any manual indexing.  It is the iindex providded in 'col.3' from your example.  If the index is in sequence and the values should. be replaced based on that index, it should work no matter how many. rows